# Trying to figure out a less clunky way of utilising a single UITableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableViewController segueing to a UIViewController. 
I have made a global `counter` to keep track of what row in the UITableView was selected. Because depending on what row selected some information in the presented UIViewController will change.

I think its possible to tidy it up so that the `dayx` segue only has to be called once and the `counter` can change accordingly depending on what row is selected? But I am having trouble figuring it out.

This is what I currently have, it works but seems messy?:

```
//what happens when row is selected
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        counter = 0
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        counter = 1
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        counter = 2
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        counter = 3
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        counter = 4
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 5 {
        counter = 5
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 6 {
        counter = 6
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: why not to use this `counter = indexPath.row
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

Swift 4.0

```
indexPath.flatMap {
    print($0) 
    counter = $0
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
}
```

Later:

```
let _ = indexPath.compactMap {
     counter = $0
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
 }
```

To understand the basics of `flatMap`. Read this article [Replacing flatMap With compactMap](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/replacing-flatmap-with-compactmap/)

### Update

If all your rows are intended to do a `performSegue`. Simple:

```
//what happens when row is selected
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   counter = indexPath.row
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you are usign flatMap or compactmap?

Comment: @SahilManchanda while the question is to fix a messy code. Looping through indexPath with compatMap is useful if the OP later tried to do extra things rather than just performSegue. I have provided a cleaner solution, if not in that case

Comment: According to current code, OP doesn't need mapping system :)

Comment: I don't think that you're in the appropriate position to decide if he needs or not. Thank you